# How to narrow down the soup.find result and output only relevant text?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

[image: Screenshot of the output i get from my code.]

Every football players wikipedia page has something named "infobox" where the career is displayed.

My goal is to scrape only the highlighted data from wikipedia pages of football players.

I have gotten this far, im able to output the "infobox" segment of the player in text like this. But the only information I want is the highlighted one.

How do I narrow the result so I only get the highlighted text as my output?

If you feel like you might now the answer please ask questions if necessary because I feel like it is hard to formulate my question good.

Comment: How can the highlighted information be distinguished from the other? What is the rule for this?

Comment: Like in the code for the wikipedia page?

Comment: If possible find the rule based on the HTML code, e. g. a special CSS class used. If not possible find something in the text itself.

Comment: All this information can be found in one table called "infobox". I think part of the solution is to "dig" even further in this big table of information.

Comment: Very interesting question that could still use some improvement - On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. May also take a short read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  Would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The infobox table is a succession of `<tr></tr` tags.
Globally we are looking for the `<tr></tr` tag located immediately after the one whose text is "Seniorlag*"

You could do it like this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

infobox = soup.find('table', {'class': 'infobox'})

tr_tags = infobox.find_all('tr')

for tr in tr_tags:
    if tr.text == "Seniorlag*":
        # Search for the following tr tag
        next_tr = tr.find_next_sibling('tr')
        print(next_tr.text)
```

output

```
År2003–20042004–20052004–20212021–

Klubb Barcelona C Barcelona B Barcelona Paris Saint-Germain

SM (GM) 10 00(5)22 00(6)520 (474)39 0(13)
```

Comment: No problem. While searching I find out that there is even more simple, you can write `tr_seniorlag=infobox.find('tr',text="Seniorlag*")` and `next_tr=tr_seniorlag.find_next_sibling('tr)`. Have a nice day.

Comment: What would this replace in my original code? I don't quite understand where to put it

Comment: Instead of doing `for tr in tr_tags: if tr.text == "Seniorlag*"`, you can directly access the right tag with `infobox.find('tr',text="Seniorlag*")` . It does exactly the same as the code I showed, but it's shorter

Answer (score 0):

Just in addition to approach of @Vincent Lagache, that answers the question well, you could also deal with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) ([more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)) to find your elements:

```
soup.select_one('tr:has(th:-soup-contains("Seniorlag")) + tr').text
```

Invoke `dict comprehension` and [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string-generators) to extract the strings:

```
{
    list(e.stripped_strings)[0]:list(e.stripped_strings)[1:] 
    for e in soup.select('tr:has(th:-soup-contains("Seniorlag")) + tr table td')
}
```

This results in a `dict` that on the one hand is already structured and can therefore be easily reused, for example creating a `Dataframe`

```
{'År': ['2003–2004', '2004–2005', '2004–2021', '2021–'], 'Klubb': ['Barcelona C', 'Barcelona B', 'Barcelona', 'Paris Saint-Germain'], 'SM (GM)': ['10', '(5)', '22', '(6)', '520 (474)', '39', '(13)']}
```

##### Example

This example also includes some pre- and postprocessing steps like [`decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) to eliminate unwanted tags and splitting column with tuples with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

for hidden in soup.find_all(style='visibility:hidden;color:transparent;'):
    hidden.decompose()

d = {
    list(e.stripped_strings)[0]:list(e.stripped_strings)[1:] 
    for e in soup.select('tr:has(th:-soup-contains("Seniorlag")) + tr table td')
    }

d['SM (GM)'] = ' '.join(d['SM (GM)']).split()
d['SM (GM)'] = list(zip(d['SM (GM)'][0::2], d['SM (GM)'][1::2]))

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df[['SM', 'GM']] = pd.DataFrame(df['SM (GM)'].tolist(), index=df.index)

df
```

##### Output

|  | År | Klubb | SM (GM) | SM | GM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2003–2004 | Barcelona C | ('10', '(5)') | 10 | (5) |
| 1 | 2004–2005 | Barcelona B | ('22', '(6)') | 22 | (6) |
| 2 | 2004–2021 | Barcelona | ('520', '(474)') | 520 | (474) |
| 3 | 2021– | Paris Saint-Germain | ('39', '(13)') | 39 | (13) |

Comment: Yes!!! thank you, this was my next step. great!

Comment: When I add your code my output doesn't look like yours. What I would like is the first example but I can't make it work.

Comment: Could you shortly clarify what you exactly mean is not working and what is expected?

Comment: Yes of course. I copied your 2 lines of code to get the output that is called a dict(?). But when i run my code the output looks the same as before.

Comment: You may still print your infobox? This is the part from example that will give you the dict `...

d = {
    list(e.stripped_strings)[0]:list(e.stripped_strings)[1:] 
    for e in soup.select('tr:has(th:-soup-contains("Seniorlag")) + tr table td')
    }
print(d)
`